# Symfony - Pass ZipArchive (PHP core class) class through service container

Tags: php, symfony

I need to pass ZipArchive class as a dependency for one of my class. I hope it is possible to do but no idea how to define in services.yml file.

Any idea please.

Comment: why not just instantiate it in the class itself? If its core then that should be no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd instantiate the core php object in the service construct and provide a setter to override this object (ie for testing later on):

services.yml:

```
app.my_service:
    class: AppBundler\Services\MyService
```

AppBundle\Services\MyService:

```
namespace AppBundle\Services;

class MyService
{
    protected $ziparchive;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ziparchive = new ZipArchive();
    }

    public function setZipArchive(\ZipArchive $zipArchive)
    {
        $this->zipArchive = $zipArchive;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Comment: this should be all you need.

Comment: I did something similar to this solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can pass your ZipArchive class as service's argument

First, you need to create service for ZipArchive

```
services:
    lib.ziparchive:
        class: Lib\ZipArchive   #your ZipArchive Class Namespace
```

Then you can pass `lib.ziparchive` to your class service

```
    app.my_service:
        class: AppBundler\Services\MyService
        arguments: ['lib.ziparchive']
```

In your MyService Class, you need to create constructor.

```
namespace AppBundle\Services;

use Lib\ZipArchive

class MyService
{
    protected $ziparchive;

    public function __construct(ZipArchive $ziparchive)
    {
        $this->ziparchive = $ziparchive;
    }

}
```

Check more detail for [service container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html)

Hope it help.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, bu my problem is ZipArchive is a PHP core class can we inject core classes through the container ? I am getting error "'\\ZipArchive'" is not a valid class name for the "zip_archive" service.

Comment: Maybe symfony documentation about [class_loader](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader/class_map_generator.html) is all you need.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did something similar to LMS94's answer